# Custom master page

Tags: sharepoint-designer, navigation, custom-masterpage

I create master page inherited from v4.master and one layout page. I dont know how I can add standart Quik Lunch menu to my master page. At now I was tried copy-paste content from some created in SPD 2010 web page from Content control (PlaceHolderLeftNavBar) but in my layout page left menu isn't displayed. Also I tried copy-paste content from v4/master PlaceHolderLeftNavBar control.
What's I do not so?

Comment: can you please post relivant code from the master page and its correlating layouts page and well be able to help :)

Comment: I fix this issue. Simple I was deleted contents from Content with ControlPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" and this make me happy.

Answer (score 0):

Content control for placeholder PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead was content with linked style who hide Content control for Quik Lunch placeholder. After I was deleted this content Quik Lunch are displayed fine.